# Как объединить массивы PHP

Tags: php

Есть массивы такого вида:

```
[0]
(
    [httpCode] => Array
        (
            [Afghanistan] => 200
            [Aland Islands] => 200
            [Albania] => 200
        )
    [url] => Array
        (
            http://....
            http://....
            http://....
        )
)

[1]
(
    [httpCode] => Array
        (
            [Andorra] => 200
            [Angola] => 200
            [Anguilla] => 200
        )
    [url] => Array
        (
            http://....
            http://....
            http://....
        )
)
```

как их объединить чтобы получилось

```
Array
(
[httpCode] => Array
    (
        [Afghanistan] => 200
        [Aland Islands] => 200
        [Albania] => 200
        [Andorra] => 200
        [Angola] => 200
        [Anguilla] => 200
    )
[url] => Array
    (
        http://....
        http://....
        http://....
        http://....
        http://....
        http://....
    )
```

)

Comment: Разобрать и собрать заново )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.array-merge-recursive.php

```
$result_array = array_merge_recursive($first_array, $second_array);
```